# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 400 (Bad Request) when Using ASP.net Identity with xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asp.net-identity

Here Iam Trying to Register A user Using REST Using Xamarin.forms
but everry Time I Post The Httpclient I returns This Error

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 400 (Bad Request)

I Tried Every thig But Always The same Error Here Is MY  RegisterService Class

```
private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://MyIP:49932/api/Account/Register";
        public async Task Register(string username, string password, string confirmPassword)
        {
            RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel
            {
                ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword,
                Password = password,
                Email = username
            };


            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            try
            {
                var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebServiceUrl, httpContent);
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
}
}
}
```

and this is the Api From AccountController

```
   // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        //string UserName, string Password,string ConfirmPassword
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        user.RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now;
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Edit*

The Registermodel

```
public class RegisterModel
    { 
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

The RegisterBindingModel

```
 public class RegisterBindingModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Please Anyone Help ME Ihave Been Stuck For A Week Now

Thanx IN Advance

Comment: show definitions of `RegisterModel` and `RegisterBindingModel` is could be possible that the properties of these two models don't match exactly and if `RegisterBindingModel` on action is null or missing a required property you will get invalid model state.

Comment: Need more info, Can you post out `RegisterBindingModel ` and the possible response contend with the Bad Request you're getting?

Comment: Thank you For Your response and I Added The RegisterModel and the RegisterBindingmodel to the orignal Post

Comment: Models look ok at first glance. When debugging are the properties of the model reaching the action populated?

Comment: yes its populated

Comment: Check the model state and see why it is invalid.

Comment: it doesnot say but the geterrorresult says  `{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2016 16:13:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Content-Length: 122
}}`